# What does the phrase "enable traffic to exit" mean in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the whole sentence from which the phrase comes:

> One way of making sure the pedestrians are safe is to increase signage of the intersections. A keep clear sign will be erected at the junction of Evelyn Street and Hill Street, **to enable traffic to exit at all times**.

What does the phrase "enable traffic to exit" mean in the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Enable* in that case means "make possible."

You can rewrite the highlighted phrase as "to allow the traffic to exit at all times."

Comment: @jwpat7 actually I want to ask meaning of `exit`

Answer (score 1):

I think the second sentence is poorly written. With the leading sentence mentioning pedestrians, I think the problem at the intersection is that vehicular traffic is entering the intersection when it can not be sure to clear it, and probably blocking pedestrian crosswalks. They plan to erect signs to remind traffic to make sure to not enter the intersection if they can't clear it. So instead of "enable", perhaps "remind"!